# How to pass v-for index to other components

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, v-for

I'm making a shopping cart app with Vue. This is the products component. I've fetched data from the api. I want to show the chosen product in the cart.

```html
<template>
  <div id="products"  >
      <div id="container"> 
          <div v-for="(product,index) in products " :key="index" id="product" >
            <img :src="products[index].image" alt="">
             <p>desc: {{products[index].description}}</p>
             <p>name: {{products[index].name}}</p>
             <p>price: $ {{products[index].price}} </p>
         </div>
      </div>
     
  </div>
</template>
```

How to pass the index to cart component so I can show information in it.
I know I should pass it to the App.vue first but don't really know how to do so

```html
<template>
  <div id="cart">
      <div class="px-3 py-2">
        <div >
            <p>{{products[index].description}}</p>
            <p>{{products[index].name}}</p>
            <img class="cart-img" src="products[index].image"  fluid thumbnail alt="">
            <b-form-spinbutton id="sb-inline"  inline></b-form-spinbutton>
            <p>{{products[index].price}}</p>
        </div>
       
      </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: <div v-for="(product,index) in products " :key="index" id="product" @click="someMethod(index)" >

in someMethod you can use the index

Comment: On a side note, in ```<div id="products"  >```, since you are using ```v-for```, you should access the individual product properties like this ```product.description```, not ```products[index].description```.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass data around across components, you have a few options.

The first would be to use emits to pass the data up through the parent components to the **App.vue**

You would then pass it down to whatever components you want via props.

This approach introduces two problems: prop drilling and a confusing data flow

Prop drilling is when you need to pass an element through the props of multiple children which can get messy, confusing and reduce performance (re-rendering when props change) - especially when you have to provide this data to multiple components.

The problem with the data flow is that you now have data travelling up through components then back down. It makes it hard to pin-point the immediate source of the state and makes your state harder to debug.

If you're using Vue2, the solution you're looking for is Vuex. Vuex allows you to create a "central store" of your state data that other components can easily access.

You can set the value of the state in one component, and access it in another without passing data up and down between components.

You can take a look at the [Vuex getting started guide](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/) for more info.

If you are using Vue3, you can implement [provide/inject](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-provide-inject.html) which is Vue's answer to React context and reduces need for more complex boilerplate just to solve prop drilling.