# Forward basiauth to axios

Tags: vue.js, axios, basic-authentication

I have a site which makes an Axios request.  Both the backend and vuejs frontend are on the same domain, and have the same basic auth covering them.

The issue is that whilst the pages load, as soon as an Axios request is made, it asks me again for the basic auth, which doesn't even work if I fill in the details.

Now I imagine I need to pass through the basic auth details somehow, but none of the things I have tried work (and example being below).

If anyone has any tips on passing through the auth token from the parent page to the axios request, that would be great.

```
const requestOne = axios.get(requestUrl)
const requestTwo = axios.get(requestUrl)
axios
  .all([requestOne, requestTwo])
  .then(
    axios.spread((...responses) => {
      <some code here>
    })
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

I just answered a similar question with the 3 ways to pass around data in Vue.

You might find it helpful: [How to pass v-for index to other components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67532566/how-to-pass-v-for-index-to-other-components)

However, in my opinion, the best approach would be to create a Vue plugin with your Axios client and an init method.

Consider this following (untested) example:

**axiosClient.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';

let instance;

export const getInstance = () => instance;

export const useAxios = () => {
    if (instance) return instance;

    instance = new Vue({
        data() {
            return {
                client: null,
            }
        }
    });

    methods: {
        init(authToken) {
            this.client = axios.create({
                headers: {'Authorization': authToken }
            });
        }
    }
}

export const axiosPlugin = {
    install(Vue) {
        Vue.prototype.$axios = useAxios();
    },
};

Vue.use(axiosPlugin);
```

Once installed, you can access this in your components using `$axios.init(...)` and `$axios.client`.

You can even write API methods directly onto the plugin as well and interact with Vuex through the plugin!

You may need to tweak the plugin a little (and keep in mind this is Vue2 syntax) as I wrote this directly into StackOverflow.

You can also pass any other default values or configuration options through to the axios client by providing options to the plugin and accessing them within init.

You can learn more about plugins here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html

Comment: I am a little confused by this on reading it, how is it retrieving the authToken from the browser/request?  It looks like it would still require me to pass it in using init(authToken).  Thanks for your time

Comment: I must have misunderstood. You said about passing through the auth token. I thought you meant across pages :)

Comment: If you want to retrieve it from the request to use it, you need to access where it is returned (either the response body or the headers in the response). Then you need to store it somewhere persistent for the session so it can be reused :) Any of the methods in my link or in my answer will let you re-use the token

Comment: How would I go about doing that?  I had originally expected it to be automatically passed through to axios (as both are on the same domain), but that doesn't appear to be the case.  Also from my understanding vue doesn't actually have access to those headers either.

Comment: Axios has access to the headers if it's same origin. Keep in mind, axios is async so you need to await:  `const { headers } = await axios.get(requestUrl, config)`. In this example you are destructing the header response of an axios request

Comment: Thanks @jordan I have edited my issue description to show my full axios request, as it is using `then` which I believe achieves the same thing as `await` in this case.  So my task is to get it to recognise the headers, you mention "destructing the header response" which feels like something I should read up on.  If you have something I can read to understand this that would be great.